# How to config iPhone video streaming from Apache?

Tags: iphone, video-streaming

I have an Apache HTTP server with mod_h264_streaming module installed. It works fine for all cases, except the iPhone. What can be the reason?

Comment: How exactly does it behave on the iPhone? Does it completely refuse to load or is it not possible to jump around in the vid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue. The problem was an encoding of the content, but I didn't discover it earlier, since the module worked, if I played the whole movie, but not if I used 'virtual clip' feature. The above means thate `http://host:port/name.mp4` works fine, but `http://host:port/name.mp4?start=200&end=500` doesn't work. I thought that if it is codec problem it should not work in both cases. However after change of encoding to recommended at mod_h264_streaming module site, the issue disappeared.